# Pointer being realloc'd was not allocated, set a breakpoint in malloc_error_break to debug

Tags: c, xcode, gcc

I've been developing this very simple C game on Windows where I've used the command `gcc matches.c -o ./matches` to compile it.
I've imported the code on my Mac and I recompiled it using `gcc` and `clang`.
Using both techniques the program completely crashes sometimes closing my terminal session and outputs this.

```
matches(54122,0x1137715c0) malloc: *** error for object 0x7ffee9e8ba40: pointer being realloc'd was not allocated
matches(54122,0x1137715c0) malloc: *** set a breakpoint in malloc_error_break to debug
Abort trap: 6

Broadcast Message from _appleevents@(myname).local                                
        (no tty) at 20:33 CET...                                               

matches(54122,0x1137715c0) malloc: *** error for object 0x7ffee9e8ba40: pointer
 being realloc'd was not allocated
```

The code was completely bug free on Windows.

I think it has to do with xcode or something similar.
Does anyone know how to solve this issue?

By the way, here's the code. The program crashes in the setup function upon `getline()`

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

void show_matches(int n);
void setup(int *numberOfPlayersA, int *gamemodeA, int *numberOfMatchesA);
void changePlayersTurn(int *currentPlayerA, int numberOfPlayers);
int random_move();

int main(void) {
  char *input;
  int currentPlayer = 1;
  size_t n = 0;
  int numberOfPlayers = 0;
  int gamemode = 0;
  int numberOfMatches = 0;
  int move = 0;

  setup(&numberOfPlayers, &gamemode, &numberOfMatches);
  show_matches(numberOfMatches);

  while (numberOfMatches >= 1) {
    printf("\033[1;31m");
    printf("\n\nPlayer %d> ", currentPlayer);
    printf("\033[0m");

    if (gamemode == 2 || currentPlayer == 1) {
      getline(&input, &n, stdin);
      move = atoi(input);

      if (move > 3 || move < 1 ) {
           move = 1;
      }
    } else {
      int randomMove = random_move();
      move = randomMove;
      printf("%d", randomMove);
    }



    numberOfMatches -= move;
    show_matches(numberOfMatches);


    if (numberOfMatches >= 1) {
      changePlayersTurn(&currentPlayer, numberOfPlayers);
    }
  }


  printf("\n\nPlayer %d lost\n\n", currentPlayer);

  return 0;
}

void setup(int *numberOfPlayersA, int *gamemodeA, int *numberOfMatchesA) {
  char *input;
  size_t n = 0;

  printf("--The matches--\n\n");
  printf("Do you plan on playing against:\n\t1. The computer\n\t2. Other persons\n\n(1 / 2) > ");
  getline(&input, &n, stdin);
  printf("1");
  *gamemodeA = atoi(input);
  printf("2");
  if (*gamemodeA == 2) {
    printf("\n\nPlease enter the number of players: ");
    getline(&input, &n, stdin);
    *numberOfPlayersA = atoi(input);
  }
  printf("Enter the number of matches: ");
  getline(&input, &n, stdin);
  *numberOfMatchesA = atoi(input);
  *numberOfPlayersA = 2;
  printf("4");
}

void changePlayersTurn(int *currentPlayerA, int numberOfPlayers) {
  if (*currentPlayerA == numberOfPlayers) {
    *currentPlayerA = 1;
  } else {
    *currentPlayerA += 1;
  }
}

void show_matches(int n) {
  for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
    printf("|");
  }
}

int random_move() {
  int num = (rand() % (3 - 1 + 1)) + 1;
  return num;
}
```

Comment: By that I want to reply, I know right tho the error persists

Comment: You must check the return value from `getline`, as with any user input function.

Comment: @DiegoROJAS you missed to initialize _input_ this is why you have your error,  some _free_ are also missing, see my answer

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In *main* :

> ```
>  char *input;
>  ...
>  getline(&input, &n, stdin);
> ```

you call *getline* without initializing *input*, if the (undefined) value is not NULL *getline* will freed it and because it is not the address of an allocated block you have your error

you need for instance :

```
  input = NULL;
  getline(&input, &n, stdin);
  move = atoi(input);

  if (move > 3 || move < 1 ) {
       move = 1;
  }
  free(input);
```

You have a similar error in *setup* :

> ```
> char *input;
> ...
> getline(&input, &n, stdin);
> ...
> getline(&input, &n, stdin);
> ```

you need to set *input* to NULL before the first call of *getline*, and you need a *free* after the last call, for instance :

```
char *input;
...
input = NULL;
getline(&input, &n, stdin);
...
getline(&input, &n, stdin);
*numberOfMatchesA = atoi(input);
free(input);
```

Additional remarks :

- you miss to check the result of *getline*
- to use *atoi* is not secure, you get 0 if the user enter something wrong, better to use *strtod* or *sscanf*
- in *main* rather than to force 1 when the input value if not between 1 and 3  it seems better to redo the input

Comment: Thank you so much for your very detailed and clear answer. Do you have any idea why the program doesn't crash on windows?